# how to launch seperate browser for each test in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, conftest

while running test_login.py , 3 browsers should be launched and verify the tests but only one is getting launched and second test is failing as second is continuing after first test steps.

*********** Conftest.py********** below is conftest file

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def setup(request):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get("https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/Login")
        driver.maximize_window()
        request.cls.driver = driver
    
        yield
        driver.close()
```

***********test_login.py*********** this test file contains 3 tests to verify

```
import pytest
from pages.loginpage import PageLogin


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestLogin:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def class_setup(self):
        self.tl = PageLogin(self.driver)
        

    @pytest.mark.login
    def test_login1(self):
        self.tl.enter_user_name("sysadm")
        self.tl.enter_password("sysadm")
        self.tl.click_login()

    

    def test_empty_user_pwd(self):
        # self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.tl.enter_user_name("")
        self.tl.enter_password("")
        self.tl.click_login()
        if self.tl.error_text() == 'Login error: Enter your username.':
            assert True
        else:
            assert False

    def test_empty_pwd(self):
        # self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.tl.enter_user_name("sysadm")
        self.tl.enter_password("")
        self.tl.click_login()
        if self.tl.error_text() == 'Login error: Enter your password.':
            assert True
        else:
            assert False
```

********* PageLogin*********** this is loginpage where all the xpaths were defined

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class PageLogin(SelectCustomer):
    textbox_username_id = "user"
    textbox_password_id = "pass"
    button_login_xpath = "//input[@value='Log In']"
    get_error_text_xpath = "//p[@class='error']"

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def enter_user_name(self, username):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.textbox_username_id).send_keys(username)

    def enter_password(self, password):
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, self.textbox_password_id).send_keys(password)

    def click_login(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.button_login_xpath).click()

    def error_text(self):
        returned_error_text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.get_error_text_xpath).text
        return returned_error_text
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Why do you want to run tests in different browsers ?

Comment: I apologize, i am unable understand what is going on.

Comment: First i have created test_login1 to verify success of login then i have created test_empty_user_pwd to check login behavior when i provide empty user and password but test_empty_user_pwd is failing with "No such element exception" as login was successful in previous section. Ideally again website should be launched and enter empty user and pwd but that is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after changing code in conftest.py below code: able to launch separate browser for each test case

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
driver = None


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(request, browser, url):
    global driver
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    elif browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
    elif browser == "edge":
        driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()


#this will get the value of CLI/Hooks
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")
    parser.addoption("--url")


#This will return the browser value to setup method
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")


#This will return the url value to setup method
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def url(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--url")
```